# How to get token for sending Slack ephemeral message

Tags: slack-api

I am developing a Slack app with a slash command.
When command is executed, Slack send to my Web API a POST request contains channel ID, user ID, **token**, etc.
I want to send an ephemeral message back to the channel.
This API (https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postEphemeral) requires a token.

Is that the token in the request I received above?
If not, how can I get that token?

For more information, the Slack workspace and channel were created by myself.

Reponse from Slack API:

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "error": "not_authed",
    "warning": "missing_charset",
    "response_metadata": {
        "warnings": [
            "missing_charset"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token you receive from the Slack request is a verification token, but you need a user or bot user token for API methods.

The [verification token](https://api.slack.com/docs/token-types#verification) can be used to verify that the request you receive really is from Slack. However that approach is outdated and you should used signed secret instead.

To get a [user token](https://api.slack.com/docs/token-types#user) you need to install you Slack app to a workspace. This can either be done on the [Slack app management page](https://api.slack.com/internal-integrations#easy_installation) or via an [Oauth process](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth) if you want to install it on other / multiple workspaces.

However, you do not need to call an API method (or a user token) in order to produce an ephemeral response to a slash command. Simple [respond directly](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands#responding_to_commands) to the request from Slack with your message in valid JSON or [send your message to the `response_url`](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands#responding_response_url) you got in the request from Slack.

Comment: Direct response was not what I need because I was looking for a kind of callback mechanism after some asynchronous tasks complete. Anyway, your answer gave me enough information. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Cool. Just to clarify for other readers. You can send your message to `response_url` for a delayed / async response within 30 minutes.